# why eclipse sometimes auto adds "*/"?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I'm a new user of eclipse 3.7 and dont know why eclipse always auto adds "*/" when I didnt notice. So I'm wondering why this happened? I haven't catch when it happens since when I write the same pieces of the code the second time the problem disapears.Can someone tell me how to solve it?
for example,this following really annoys me

```
public void addBall()
{
    try
    {
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        comp.add(ball);

        for (int i = 1; i <= STEPS; i++)
        {
            ball.move(comp.getBounds());
            comp.paint(comp.getGraphics());
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        }
    }
   */
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem occurred when I press **"{"** following the word **try**. It seems only happens when the corresponding **"}"** is out of current view, however I'm not really sure.Plus,the compiler didnt give me any warnings.

Comment: It adds that **where**? In your Java code? In some dialog? Can you provide some steps to reproduce this?

Comment: An example or some more information would help us figure what your problem is.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer,@Doctor Oreo sorry about that, I have reedited the quesion:)

Comment: Ok, you've got an example, but you need to tell us *what the state of the editor was*, *where* you typed *which* letter or pushed *which* button and *where* the `*/` was inserted (at the cursor position? somewhere else?)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Hope to review this question:->

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to reproduce this. Did the file compile without warnings before this happened? Is it possible that *something* confused the parser (non-compiling code sometimes does this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look at the Java code templates - possibly you triggered something there. The defined templates can be found in Preferences, the Java/Editor/Templates page.

At first look at the try template whether it contains the */; or look for similar patterns as well.

Comment: I only changed the formatter style about **braces** , all with preference **next line** and kept others default.I don't know why this should be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Eclipse automatically adds "*/" when you input "/*" and hit Enter, the same way as it automatically adds closing parenthesis.

Comment: however I didn't input any "/*", I check the **code style** preference and didn't find anything wrong.